# Is there a SQL query for demanding that a column is being filled out?

Tags: sql, function, phpmyadmin

I have created two tables in PhpMyAdmin, and I wonder if there is a SQL query that "demands" one column in each table to be filled out?

I have one column called "time" and one called "speed".

Comment: select * from tablename where columnname is not null; ?

Comment: Hi. Please specify what do you mean by "demands"? To be sure that there will be any value for each row? If so just `NOT NULL` should do a job. Or rather you mean that there should be some default value?

Comment: Can you describe more thoroughly what you need? There are various mechanisms like `NOT NULL` to enforce that a column get a value or the row insert will fail, and other mechanisms like requiring a column's value match a value in another table as a foreign key

Comment: Yes I want to make sure that the will be value in each row in the specific column called "speed". Will it be enough to write: "Speed INTEGER NOT NULL" then? Or do I need something more?

Comment: Just try it. With `NOT NULL` db should throw an error if such not provided. And this is about `NULL` values, it does not cover empty strings, `0`, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

The sql Constraints **NOT NULL** ensures that a column cannot have a NULL value

You can find more in this links:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_constraints.asp

https://www.sqlshack.com/commonly-used-sql-server-constraints-not-null-unique-primary-key/